# How do I get 2 groups on the bar plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot of these data points with the two groups before and after. The y axis is the percent and the x axis is the antibiotic. I want the groups before and after to be separated, but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Data:

[image: Data]
[image: Data Continued]

```
#Bar chart of Before and after ####
d1 <- MDRclasslong0611 
d2 <- MDRclasslong1217
All <- rbind(
  within(d1, {DS <- 'Before'}),
  within(d2, {DS <- 'After'}))

names(All)[3] <- "Antibiotic"
names(All)[3] <- "Number of Isolates"
names(All)[3] <- "Percent"
names(All)[4] <- "Group"

ggplot(All, aes(factor(Antibiotic), Percent, fill = factor(Antibiotic)))+  
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position="dodge") + 
  xlab("Antimicrobial Class") + 
  ylab("Percent Resistant Isolates")+
  ggtitle("Antimicrobial Resistance: 2012-2017")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), limits = c(0,90))+
  scale_fill_manual("Class", values=colors, labels = labels)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), text 
        = element_text(size=16), legend.title = element_text(size=14), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image: Bar Chart I get]

Comment: Have you considered using facets to compare before and after?

Comment: Would that give me a graphical representation similar to a bar plot?

Comment: Yeah just try `+ facet_wrap(~ Group)`.

Comment: That gave two separate bar graphs with the groups, is there a way that I can have the bars directly next to each other? Thanks!

Comment: please provide your data as code

Comment: You might simply have forgotten `aes(group = Group)` in the `geom_bar()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario with to possible solution. Please let me know.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# tweak data
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>%
  mutate(Group = fct_relevel(Group, "Before", "After")) 
 
  # Plot 1
  ggplot(df) + aes(x = Antibiotic, y = Percent, fill=Group) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(Percent,1),"%")), vjust=-0.25, color="black",
              position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5) +
  xlab("Antimicrobial Class") + 
  ylab("Percent Resistant Isolates")+
  ggtitle("Antimicrobial Resistance: 2012-2017")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.25))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), limits = c(0,90))+
  #scale_fill_manual("Class", values=colors, labels = labels)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), text 
        = element_text(size=16), legend.title = element_text(size=14), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
  
  # Plot 2
  # The palette with grey:
  cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7", "#999999")
  
  ggplot(df) + aes(x = Group, y = Percent, fill=Antibiotic) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(Percent,1),"%")), vjust=-0.25, color="black",
              position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5) +
    xlab("Antimicrobial Class") + 
    ylab("Percent Resistant Isolates")+
    ggtitle("Antimicrobial Resistance: 2012-2017")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.25))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), limits = c(0,90))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), text 
          = element_text(size=16), legend.title = element_text(size=14), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

## Plot 1

[image]

## Plot 2

[image]

## Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Antibiotic = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "F", 
"F", "Mo", "Mo", "Pen", "Pen", "Ph", "Ph"), `Number of Isolates` = c(176, 
140, 117, 105, 117, 103, 174, 137, 11, 2, 147, 110, 164, 134), 
Percent = c(82.242991, 89.74359, 54.672897, 67.307692, 54.672897, 
66.025641, 81.308411, 87.820513, 5.140187, 1.282051, 68.691589, 
70.512821, 76.635514, 85.897436), Group = c("Before", "After", 
"Before", "After", "Before", "After", "Before", "After", 
"Before", "After", "Before", "After", "Before", "After")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(Antibiotic = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Number of Isolates` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Percent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```